# Как отправить ajax запрос по клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно что бы при клике на кнопку `One\two\three\etc...` на сервер пришел ajax запрос с содержанием `$_POST['name']=value;`
Никак не могу понять как сформировать `data` для ajax-запроса.

HTML-форма

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form-inline d-inline" id="someId" method="post">
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="1">one</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="2">two</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="3">three</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="4">four</button>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <div class="input-group mx-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Количество">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    // Stop form from sending request to server
    e.preventDefault();

    var btn = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "name": btn.val(),
        'input': $('input').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(er) {
        console.log(er);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form-inline d-inline" id="someId" method="post">
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="1">one</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="2">two</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="3">three</button>
  <button class="dropdown-item btn" name="name" value="4">four</button>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <div class="input-group mx-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Количество">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  ...
  <input name="name" class="inputForName" type="hidden" />
</form>

$('#someId .dropdown-item').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this).closest("form");
  $form.find(".inputForName").val($(this).attr("value"));
  $.ajax({
    ...
    data: $form.serialize();
    ...
  });
  $form.find(".inputForName").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас одна форма, необходимо для каждого запроса делать свою.

Либо в противном случае попробуйте написать для каждой кнопки `onclick="send_request(type)"`

И далее через теги `<script></script>` вбить следующий код:

```
    $("#selector").load("/file.php", {param:value,param2:value2},function()
    {
        //actions after response
    });
```

Не забудьте считать `value` через `$("selector").val();`

Comment: Я отслеживаю событие `$('#someID .dropdown-item').click`, по этому событию я могу отправить ajax запрос, нужно что бы на сервер пришло `name=value`, я только никак не могу сообразить как сформировать данные поля `data` d ajax-запросе

Comment: Я понимаю. Вам нужно прочитать значение по id, а не name.